# OpenCL CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE when calling any enqueue command

Tags: c++, c++11, opencl, gpgpu

I get everytime I call an enqueue command on a command queue the return value `CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE`.

The boiler plate stuff (placed in the ctor) is running very well, but when I call the function which handles the kernel execution it breaks down at the first position where a enqueueing is done.

I think my kernel is quite correct, because there are no errors thrown by any of the OpenCL C Compilers (AMD's for the vga card and INTEL's for the processor). Also an empty kernel showed up the same error.

Perhaps it is just a small crumb which causes this issue but I don't see it.

The following shows you my constructor which should be work fine:

```
std::vector<cl_platform_id>             this->OCLPlatformList;
std::vector<std::vector<cl_device_id>>  this->OCLDevicesList;
std::vector<cl_context>                 this->OCLContext;

className::ctor()
{
    this->FFT_SIZE_3 = this->configuration->getFFTSize(FFT_MULT::FFT_3);

    cl_int err;

    this->samplesInBuffer = new std::complex<float>[this->FFT_SIZE_3]();

    // query OCL Platforms
    cl_uint platformCount;
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(0,NULL,&platformCount);
    OCLCheckErr(err);

    cl_platform_id* plBuffer = new cl_platform_id[platformCount];
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(platformCount,plBuffer,NULL);
    OCLCheckErr(err);

    this->OCLPlatformList.resize((unsigned int)platformCount);
    this->OCLDevicesList.resize((unsigned int)platformCount);
    this->OCLContext.resize((unsigned int)platformCount);
    for(cl_uint i = 0; i < platformCount; i++)
    {
        this->OCLPlatformList[i] = plBuffer[i];
    }
    delete[] plBuffer;


    // query OCL Devices
    cl_uint devCount;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->OCLPlatformList.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        err = clGetDeviceIDs(this->OCLPlatformList[i],CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL,0,NULL,&devCount);
        OCLCheckErr(err);

        cl_device_id* devBuffer = new cl_device_id[devCount];
        err = clGetDeviceIDs(this->OCLPlatformList[i],CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL,devCount,devBuffer,NULL);
        OCLCheckErr(err);

        this->OCLDevicesList[i].resize((unsigned int)devCount);

        std::cout << std::endl << "Platform #" << i << ": " <<    OCLGetPlatformName(this->OCLPlatformList[i]) << std::endl;
        for(cl_uint j = 0; j < devCount; j++)
        {
            this->OCLDevicesList[i][j] = devBuffer[j];
            std::cout << "|-- Device #" << j << ": " << OCLGetDeviceName(this->OCLDevicesList[i][j]) << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        delete[] devBuffer;


    }


    // create OCL Context
    cl_context_properties* cprops = new cl_context_properties[3];
    cprops[0] = ;
    cprops[2] = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->OCLPlatformList.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        cl_device_id* devBuffer = new cl_device_id[this->OCLDevicesList[i].size()];
        unsigned int j = 0;
        for(std::vector<cl_device_id>::iterator it = this->OCLDevicesList[i].begin(); it != this->OCLDevicesList[i].end(); ++it)
        devBuffer[j++] = *it;

        cprops[1] = (cl_context_properties)this->OCLPlatformList[i];
        this->OCLContext[i] = clCreateContext(cprops,(cl_uint)this->OCLDevicesList[i].size(),devBuffer,NULL,NULL,&err);
    OCLCheckErr(err);

    }
    delete[] cprops;


    // create OCL Command Queue
    cl_queue_properties qprops[] =
    {
        CL_QUEUE_PROPERTIES,CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE_DEFAULT,0
    };
    this->OCLComQueue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(this->OCLContext[0],this->OCLDevicesList[0][0],qprops,&err);
    OCLCheckErr(err);

    cl_int commSize;
    err = clGetCommandQueueInfo(this->OCLComQueue,CL_QUEUE_SIZE,sizeof(cl_int),&commSize,NULL);
    std::cout << this->OCLComQueue << " " << (long)commSize << std::endl;

    OCLCheckErr(OCLCompileKernelFromSource(this->OCLProgram,"Kkernel.cl",this->OCLContext[0],this->OCLDevicesList[0][0],true));

    this->kernel = clCreateKernel(this->OCLProgram,"Kkernel",&err);
    OCLCheckErr(err);


    // create OCL Buffer
    //std::complex<float> this->BufferA[this->sizeA];
    this->BufferACL = clCreateBuffer(this->OCLContext[0],(CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR),
                                            (this->sizeA * sizeof(std::complex<float>)),this->BufferA,&err);
    OCLCheckErr(err);

    //std::complex<float> this->BufferB[this->sizeB * this->k];
    this->BufferBCL = clCreateBuffer(this->OCLContext[0],(CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR),
                                            (this->sizeB * this->k * sizeof(std::complex<float>)),BufferB,&err);
    OCLCheckErr(err);

    //std::complex<float> this->BufferB[this->l * this->k];
    this->BufferCCL = clCreateBuffer(this->OCLContext[0],(CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR),
                                            (this->l * this->k * sizeof(std::complex<float>)),this->BufferC,&err);
    OCLCheckErr(err);

    err = clSetKernelArg(this->kernel,0,sizeof(this->BufferACL),(void*)&this->BufferACL);
    OCLCheckErr(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(this->kernel,1,sizeof(this->BufferBCL),(void*)&this->BufferBCL);
    OCLCheckErr(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(this->kernel,2,sizeof(this->BufferCCL),(void*)&this->BufferCCL);
    OCLCheckErr(err);
    err = clSetKernelArg(this->kernel,3,sizeof(unsigned int),(void*)&this->k);
    OCLCheckErr(err);
}
```

This is the first part of the function which should handle the kernel execution. If I comment out the enqueuing of the memory buffer it fails at enqueuing the kernel:

```
void className::func1()
{
    long c = this->k - 1;

    for(std::list<std::complex<float>>::iterator it = this->sampleHistBuffer.begin(); it != this->sampleHistBuffer.end(); ++it)
    {
        cl_int err;
        cl_event event;
        clFinish(this->OCLComQueue);
        OCLCheckErr(err);

        err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(this->OCLComQueue,this->BufferACL,CL_TRUE,0,(this->k * sizeof(std::complex<float>)),this->BufferA,0,NULL,&event);
        OCLCheckErr(err);
        cl_int state;
        do
        {
            clGetEventInfo(event,CL_EVENT_COMMAND_EXECUTION_STATUS,sizeof(state),&state,NULL);
            if(state < 0)
                throw 11;
        }
        while(state >= CL_COMPLETE);

        size_t global_item_size = this->k * this->l;
        size_t local_item_size = this->k;
        err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(this->OCLComQueue,this->kernel,1,NULL,&global_item_size,&local_item_size,0,NULL,&event);
        OCLCheckErr(err);
        do
        {
            clGetEventInfo(event,CL_EVENT_COMMAND_EXECUTION_STATUS,sizeof(state),&state,NULL);
            if(state < 0)
                throw 11;
        }
        while(state >= CL_COMPLETE);
     /*...*/
}
```

Last but not least this is the source of the kernel. It performs a multiplication on k workitems over l workgroups:

```
float2 cmult(float2 A, float2 B)
{
    float2 ret;
    ret.x = A.x * B.x;
    ret.y = A.y * B.y;

    return ret;
}

#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable
__kernel void Kkernel(__global float2* BufferA, __global float2* BufferB, __global float2* BufferC, unsigned int k)
{
    size_t sampleWrkGp = get_group_id(0);
    size_t sampleWrkId = get_local_id(0);

    BufferC[(sampleWrkId * k) + sampleWrkId] = cmult(BufferA[sampleWrkId],BufferB[(sampleWrkId * k) + sampleWrkId]);
}
```

If there are some not described functions (like `OCLCheckErr()`), you can be sure they are safe and not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating an on-device command queue (CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE_DEFAULT), and then trying to use it to enqueue commands from the host. You can only use device-side command queues from the device side. Use a regular command queue (clCreateCommandQueue) for host-side enqueues.